# Can certain spectral lines be common between two spectrums

Tags: atomic-structure

I have studied regarding atomic spectroscopy in my class and the Rydberg's formula. Suppose if I take $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{He+}$ and an electron jumps from from 2nd to 1st shell in $\ce{H}$ and from 4th to 2nd shell in $\ce{He+}$.

So according to Rydberg's formula

```
1/lamda(1)= R(1)^2(1/1^2-1/2^2)
1/lamda(2)= R(2)^2(1/2^2-1/4^2)
```

So both must be equal but I also know that each element has a unique atomic spectrum so how the above equation can be explained.

Please correct my understanding.

Comment: Chem+Math formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: The original Rydberg formula *only* works for hydrogen atoms. Even for other hydrogen-like atoms, it won't work because the nuclear charges are different and they affect the actual energy levels. There is an extended Rydberg formula that includes this but it clearly *won't* give the same wavelengths for similar transitions.

Comment: Please define $R(1)$ and $R(2)$ - do you mean the Rydberg "constant" as a function of the nuclear charge, i.e. $R(Z)$?

Comment: Also in the second equation I assume you mean 1/2^2, correct?

Comment: @matt_black Unfortunately the OP hasn't defined the symbols they use but iff I understand them they have included correctly the effect of nuclear charge in their formula - the quadratic dependence of the Rydberg constant is cancelled by the inverse square of the double quantum number. So actually I like the answer as given, a spectrum is not just one line but the full collection. If you want to quibble the exact frequency will not be the same for any number of reasons, reduced mass is possibly the simplest difference, but at the level indicated the question is a nice observation.

Answer (score 3):

Well spotted, single transitions of different elements can indeed have (nearly) identical energies, i.e. the same emission lines.

However, a spectrum is a *collection* of emission lines. That collection will be different for $\ce{He+}$ and $\ce{H}$. They may share one (or several) common lines that you indicate, but they will also have many distinct lines and thus a distinct spectrum.

It's a bit like words and letters: "apple" and "argon" share a common letter "a", but they are distinct words because they also contain other letters.

As a matter of fact, Niels Bohr made the same observation as you:

> It may be remarked that according to the theory, helium must be
> expected to emit a series of lines closely, but not exactly,
> coinciding with the lines of the ordinary hydrogen spectrum. (Niels Bohr, 1913, *[The spectra of helium and hydrogen](https://zenodo.org/records/1429570)*)

Comment: Well, not really. The nuclear charge on different elements means that the *same* transitions in isoelectronic atoms do not have the same wavelength. This is clear from the use of the version of the extended Rydberg formula that includes atom-specific factors rather than the original formula that only works for hydrogen atoms.

Comment: Sure, in the OP's example it's not the *same* transition that has a (nearly) identical wavelength. It's a different transition (n=4 --> n=2 for He+ vs. n=2 --> n=1 for H).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula#For_any_hydrogen-like_element